# probability distribution of equally possible continuous outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the probability distribution of this continuous variable $x$ below?

$x$ is a random variable which takes value in $\mathbb{R}$ with equal probability at every point. I.e. the probability density function $p(x)$ satisties
$$p(a)=p(b), \quad \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R} $$

Of course this can't be expressed by any function on $\mathbb{R}$. But how do we model this anyway?

Comment: There is no such random variable. A constant function does not integrate to $1$ so it cannot be a density function.

Comment: Exactly what @KaviRamaMurthy said, but I just want to add that this is because you're asking for a variables with values in $\mathbb{R}$. If instead you take a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then you can find such a probability distribution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And I'm aware of that. I am asking how do probability deal with such a "random variable", because, after all, we can define it by "equally possible over a set".

Comment: @Neo That is the point -- we *cannot* define it, and probability does *not* deal with it. "Equally possible over a set" can be defined under some assumptions on the set, not for *every* set.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $u:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. You would like to define $u$ such that $$\mu(a<u\leq a+\varepsilon)=\mu(b<u\leq b+ \varepsilon)>0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R},\, \varepsilon >0$$
Now partition $\mathbb{R}$ in $I_n=(-n-1,-n]\cup (n,n+1],\, n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$\mu(u\in I_n)=p_n=c \ \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
We have however that
$$\mu(u \in \mathbb{R})=\mu(X)<\infty$$
and
$$\mu(u \in \mathbb{R})=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}p_n=c \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}1=\infty$$
which is a contradiction. So there is no such $u$.